# Upgrade from openjdk-7 to openjdk-8 on debian

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, java, openjdk

I have the following Java-related packages installed on my Debian 8 machine

```
# sudo dpkg -l | grep -i java
ii  ca-certificates-java           20140324                         all          Common CA certificates (JKS keystore)
ii  java-common                    0.52                             all          Base of all Java packages
ii  libatk-wrapper-java            0.30.5-1                         all          ATK implementation for Java using JNI
ii  libatk-wrapper-java-jni:amd64  0.30.5-1                         amd64        ATK implementation for Java using JNI (JNI bindings)
ii  openjdk-7-jre:amd64            7u181-2.6.14-1~deb8u1            amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64   7u181-2.6.14-1~deb8u1            amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  tzdata-java                    2018e-0+deb8u1                   all          time zone and daylight-saving time data for use by java runtimes
```

I just want to install Java 8 but I keep running into dependencies issues:

```
# sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-8-jre : Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u171-b11-1~bpo8+1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


# sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-8-jre-headless : Breaks: ca-certificates-java (< 20160321~) but 20140324 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I upgrade to Java 8, addressing all dependencies issues at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `apt` to consider backported packages:

```
apt -t jessie-backports install openjdk-8-jre
```